# Why isn't my query inserting using bind param? but it updates using that same bind_param

Tags: php

I have a problem executing a DB insertion using bind_param, but yet i can update with the same bind_param method, but i can't insert. Here my functions for the update(the one that is working) and the insertion(the one that's not working).

```
function update()
{
    $query = "
        UPDATE " . $this->table_name . "
           SET category_key= :ck,
               product_name = :pn,
               unit_of_measurement = :uom,
               price = :pc,
               pieces = :ps,
               last_date_added = :lda,
               last_added_by = :lab,
               reorder = :rd,
               note = :no
         WHERE product_key LIKE :pk
    ";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(':ck', $this->category_key);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pn', $this->product_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':uom', $this->unit_of_measurement);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pc', $this->price);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ps', $this->pieces);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lda', $this->last_date_added);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lab', $this->last_added_by);
    $stmt->bindParam(':no', $this->note);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pk', $this->product_key);
    $stmt->bindParam(':rd', $this->reorder);

    // execute the query
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


function insert()
{
   $query = "
       INSERT INTO product_entry (
              category_key,
              product_key,
              product_name,
              unit_of_measurement,
              price,
              pieces,
              date_added,
              added_by,
              exp_date,
              store_key,
              branch_code,
              note
       ) 
       VALUES (
              :ck,
              :pk,
              :pn,
              :uom,
              :pc,
              :ps,
              :lda,
              :lab,
              :ep,
              :sk,
              :bc,
              :no
    )";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(':sk', $this->store_key);
    $stmt->bindParam(':bc', $this->branch_code);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ck', $this->category_key);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pn', $this->product_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':uom', $this->unit_of_measurement);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pc', $this->price);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ps', $this->pieces);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lda', $this->last_date_added);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lab', $this->last_added_by);
    $stmt->bindParam(':no', $this->note);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pk', $this->product_key);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ep', $this->exp_date);

    // execute the query
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is my HTML form just incase

```
<form method="post">    


<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="sk" name="store_key" value='<?php echo $product->store_key; ?>'>
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="bc" name="branch_code" value='<?php echo $product->branch_code; ?>'>
<label for="pn">Product Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pn" name="product_name" value='<?php echo $product->product_name; ?>'>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ms">Measurement</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uom" name="unit_of_measurement" value='<?php echo $product->unit_of_measurement; ?>'>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="qn">Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="3" id="pc" name="price" value='<?php echo $product->price; ?>'/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ps">Pieces</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ps" name="pieces" value='<?php echo $product->pieces; ?>'/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="rd">Re-order</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rd" name="reorder" value='<?php echo $product->reoder; ?>'/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ep">Expiry Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="ep" name="exp_date" value='<?php echo $product->exp_date; ?>'/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ab">Added By</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lab" name="last_added_by" value='<?php echo $product->last_added_by; ?>'/>
</div>`
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="no">Note</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="no" name="note"><?php echo $product->note; ?></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Note that both update and insert are called from the same class and are executed from the same form and php page which updates a product table(which works) but doesn't insert into a product_entry table.

Comment: If in your else statement you put something USEFUL like `print_r($this->conn->errorInfo());` You would have told yourself what the problem was

Comment: Why is the table hardcoded in the `insert`, but dynamic in the `update`? You SURE you're using the proper table name?

Comment: yes i am, i did that to make sure that my hardcoded method wasn't the problem. But i'll try out your guide.

Comment: from where you get pk in insert ? is it the primary key if yes just hardcode the value in the insert query as I believe the the problem is there

Comment: No the pk is the Product_key, but is it that my actual code isn't wrong? Maybe my method of posting somehow is? Like how i catch the $_POST or something

Comment: i get the pk from my readOne() function under the same class, it's what populates all the inputs from the database to the form, and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using bindValue() instead.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

$stmt->bindValue(':sk', $this->store_key);
$stmt->bindValue(':bc', $this->branch_code);
$stmt->bindValue(':ck', $this->category_key);
$stmt->bindValue(':pn', $this->product_name);
$stmt->bindValue(':uom', $this->unit_of_measurement);
$stmt->bindValue(':pc', $this->price);
$stmt->bindValue(':ps', $this->pieces);
$stmt->bindValue(':lda', $this->last_date_added);
$stmt->bindValue(':lab', $this->last_added_by);
$stmt->bindValue(':no', $this->note);
$stmt->bindValue(':pk', $this->product_key);
$stmt->bindValue(':ep', $this->exp_date);

I usualy do this way:

$stmt->execute(array(":sk"=>$this->store_key,":bc"=>$this->branch_code,":ck"=>$this->category_key,"cn"=>$this->product_name),":uom"=>$this->unit_of_measurement,":pc"=>$this->price,":ps"=>$this->pieces,":lda"=>$this->last_date_added,":lab"=>$this->last_added_by,":no"=>$this->note,":pk"=>$this->product_key,":ep"=>$this->exp_date));
```